# How to serialize class in WCF

Tags: asp.net, wcf

I don’t want my class to be displayed at the user end who is using my WCF service but it needs to be serialized, with which attribute I need to decorate my class to achieve this functionality….

I think attribute is [serializable], the reason why i am not confident, is there attribute in WCF to achieve same functionality.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use attributes `DataContract` and `DataMember` like in this example:

```
[DataContract(Name = "Account", Namespace = "http://mynamespace.schema")]
public class Account 
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true)]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = false)]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: We Will use this attribute when we need our class to be serialized and accessible(Will be displayed in the intellisence) at the client end, But my class should not be accessible to the user and it need be serialized....... Can you please give solution for this

Comment: @Harishkakani use DTO pattern to transfer data from server to client and map your internal data classes in DTO classes

Answer (score 0):

you can use [DataContractAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute.aspx)

Comment: We Will use this attribute when we need our class to be serialized and accessible(Will be displayed in the intellisence) at the client end, But my class should not be accessible to the user and it need be serialized....... Can you please give solution for this